# My Nook Simple Touch screen is no longer responding to touch reliably. How can I fix it?

Tags: nook, touchscreen, nook-simple-touch, maintenance

Over the course of several months, my Nook Simple Touch became less and less responsive to touch. It also became more and more sensitive to temperature conditions of my fingers and the environment.

I took it to a Barnes and Noble store and they suggested I tried to warm up my hands before using it. That helped a little but it's still erratic.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure that hardware related questions are a good idea. See this meta question: http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1/hardware-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Over time, grease and grime from fingers transfers to the display and can cause touch sensitivity to become erratic. Simply clean the Nook display with a water-dampened cloth and touch sensitivity will return to normal.